# Flickering when expanding a panel with an iframe

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

Im facing a problem when expanding/colapsing a panel with an iframe inside, some flickering ocurs when i toggle width with:

```
myPanel.animate({ duration:500,dynamic: true, to: { width: w } });
```

Its not an absurd amont of flickering but is far from aceptable. Im loking for a smooter way to transition the panel size, please advise.

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate my problem:

**[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2kkc)**

Comment: FYI, I don't see any flicker there on chrome.latest.

Comment: It's very subtle but is there (easy to see by the scrollbars), i trying to smooth it out